How to set up jest to understand the .js extensions in Typescript?
I have a project in Typescript, which I compile with tsc and the .js files go to a ./dist folder.
In the root directory, I have a ./test folder, in which I put a example.test.js file with a couple of tests.
when I run npm test, it produces the error:
Cannot find module '../models/OtherFile.js' from 'middleware/example.ts'.
It cannot find the .js OtherFile because it's not there. There's an OtherFile.ts in that directory, but when the tsc compiles everything, I can use a command like node ./dist/main.js and everything is in the right place and it all runs perfectly.
If I omit the file extension in the source typescript code, it finds example.ts but it produces an error whenever it finds again another .js extension, since it really doesn't exist only in the compiled folder .dist. Also, the source code wouldn't compile because it seems like it's mandatory to specify the extension.
If I use a allowImportingTsExtensions flag in tsconfig.json, I have to use noEmit as well, which is not desirable, since I need to run the application sometimes.
I figure that must be some kind of settings I'm missing.
Here's my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx":"react",
    "target": "es2017",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "module": "ESNext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}

Here is jest.config.js
export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)'],
  };

